# Many Phusion Passenger processess spawn and stick around

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, systemd

I'm using Phusion Passenger Standalone 5.3.4 with a Rails 5 application. After some load testing yielded some less then satisfactory results I decided to look at some of the processes under the hood and discovered quite a number of different Passenger-related processes, with names ranging from "Passenger Watchdog", "Passenger Core", "Passenger AppPreloader" all spawning and sticking around. They seemed to remain for a little while even after I stopped my load testing, needlessly using up precious memory on the server.

Is it normal for Passenger to be spawning dozens of these processes mentioned above for a meager amount of traffic (I was only testing with 20 concurrent users). If the quantity of these processes is normal, is it also normal for them to stick around even after the traffic has left the website?

[lots of passenger processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFm1F.png)

For additional context, I'm running all of this on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM, and I'm also leveraging Systemd in `Type=forking` config. I'm not passing any particular options to Passenger at the moment, for the most part everything is just using default configurations.

Answer (score 0):

After some further reading in their documentation, I found a few options that had a significant improvement on my application's concurrency, tuning the `max-pool-size` and `min-instances` according to their [documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/optimization/#minimizing-process-spawning) for Passenger Standalone helped considerably.

Switching from the `nginx` engine to the `builtin` engine also seemed to yield better results with my load testing.